# Cant seem to find why this Xunit test wont work in .net, it works on the frondend

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, xunit

I am trying to test a Food waste sytem in which students can reserve mealboxes so they can pick them up at a cheap price.
the test im trying to run is as follows: Dont allow someone to reserve 2 mealboxes for the same pickup date

```
        [Fact]
        //unhappy
        public void MealBox_Student_Already_Reserved_Same_Date()
        {
            // Arrange
            var repositoryManagerMock = new Mock<IRepositoryManager>();

            ServiceManager _ss = new ServiceManager(repositoryManagerMock.Object);
            
            var MealboxList = new List<MealBox>();
            
            var Student = new Student
            {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = "Test",
                LastName = "Student",
                Email = "test@gmail.com",
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-15),
                StudentNumber = "210897",
                StudyCity = City.Breda,
                MobileNumber = "0612345678",
                ReservedMealBoxes = MealboxList
            };
            
            MealboxList.Add(new MealBox
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test MealBox",
                PickupDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                LatestPickupTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
                IndicationalIs18Plus = false,
                IsHotMeal = false,
                Price = 10,
                MealType = MealType.ColdLunch,
                ExampleProductsBasedOnHistory = new List<Product>(),
                ReservedBy = Student,
                ReservedById = 1,
                OfferedAtCanteen = null,
                OfferedAtCanteenId = 1
            });
            
            var MealBox = new MealBox
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Test MealBox",
                PickupDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                LatestPickupTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
                IndicationalIs18Plus = false,
                IsHotMeal = false,
                Price = 10,
                MealType = MealType.ColdLunch,
                ExampleProductsBasedOnHistory = new List<Product>(),
                ReservedBy = null,
                ReservedById = null,
                OfferedAtCanteen = null,
                OfferedAtCanteenId = 1
            };
            
            repositoryManagerMock.Setup(x => x.MealBox.GetById(2)).Returns(MealBox);
            repositoryManagerMock.Setup(x => x.Student.GetByEmail(Student.Email)).Returns(Student);

            // Act
            ServiceResponse message = _ss.MealBox.Reserve(2, Student.Email);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal("You have already reserved a mealbox for this date", message.Message);

        }
```

this is my validator

```
        public ServiceResponse Reserve(int id, string email)
        {
            var response = new ServiceResponse();

            var student = _repositoryManager.Student.GetByEmail(email);
            if (student == null)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "Student not found";
                return response;
            }

            var mealBox = _repositoryManager.MealBox.GetById(id);
            if (mealBox == null)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "MealBox not found";
                return response;
            }

            var resultOfChecks = MealBoxReserveChecks(response, mealBox, student);
            if (!resultOfChecks.Success)
            {
                return resultOfChecks;
            }

            mealBox.ReservedById = student.Id;

            try
            {
                _repositoryManager.MealBox.Update(mealBox);
                _repositoryManager.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            response.Success = true;
            response.Message = "MealBox reserved successfully!";
            return response;
        }

        private ServiceResponse MealBoxReserveChecks(ServiceResponse response, MealBox mealBox, Student student)
        {
            if (mealBox.ReservedBy != null)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "MealBox already reserved";
                return response;
            }

            if (mealBox.IndicationalIs18Plus)
            {
                int hasToBePickedUp = Int32.Parse(mealBox.PickupDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
                int dateOfBirth = Int32.Parse(student.DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

                if (((hasToBePickedUp - dateOfBirth) / 10000) < 18)
                {
                    response.Success = false;
                    response.Message = "You are not 18+ and cannot reserve this mealbox";
                    return response;
                }
            }

            var reservedMealBoxes = _repositoryManager.MealBox.GetAll().Where(mb => mb.ReservedById == student.Id).ToList();
            
            if (reservedMealBoxes.Any(mb => mb.PickupDateTime.Day == mealBox.PickupDateTime.Day))
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "You have already reserved a mealbox for this date";
                return response;
            }

            response.Success = true;
            return response;
        }
```

in Xunit with this code my mealbox will still be reserved succesfully, which is so weird

someone know the answer to my problem?

I tried many things such as changing the way the mealbox is added to the user, but nothing worked.

the goal is to get the error that you already have a mealbox reserved for this date

Comment: Debug the test to see where it act differently than your expectation. From the quick look, maybe missing `Setup` for `GetAll` method? on the repository?

Comment: `x.MealBox.GetById(2)` returns the mealbox #2 which is not reserved yet, so you are not getting the first error. `GetAll()` is not mocked so it returns probably empty collection and hence the second check is also successful.

Comment: For better reproducability, I would not use `DateTime.Now` in the test, but rather some fixed date.

Comment: I figured it out, it had to do with the controller not getting the right info